# Phonegap EmailComposer with Attachment for iOS not working

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, email-attachments

I am using Cordova 2.2.0 for iOS.  I'm trying to implement the [Phonegap EmailComposerWithAttachments](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/EmailComposerWithAttachments) plugin and I can't seem to get the picture attachment to work.

I call:

```
window.plugins.emailComposer.showEmailComposerWithCallback(function(result){console.log(result);},"Look at this photo","Take a look at this:",[],[],[],true,[testPath]);
```

where testPath contains the path of my PNG or JPG file. e.g. ../myImage.jpg

**The Good:** The email composer comes up. I see my subject, the body of the e-mail etc.

**The Bad:** I don't see my picture included as attachment. Instead I see a small question mark (in the emulator) and a small square (on my iPad), as if the attachment was missing.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am getting "Cannot read property 'EmailComposer' of undefined" error. Also i posted this at "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25696639/how-to-send-email-in-iphone-android-using-intel-xdk". Do you have any idea. Please provide your comments. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was the path I was providing for the plugin.

When you get the path of a file, it looks like this:

```
file:///localhost/var/mobile/Applications/2BED9D97-043A-402A-B914-83F4459E8A74/myApp.app/myPicture.jpg
```

However, the EmailComposerWithAttachments plugin does not expect the path to start with

```
"file:///localhost/"
```

In order for the plugin to work, you need to change its path by taking out everything before var (file:///localhost/). So, the correct path would look like this:

```
var/mobile/Applications/2BED9D97-043A-402A-B914-83F4459E8A74/myApp.app/myPicture.jpg
```

Then it worked. I was able to use this plugin to send emails with picture attachments.

Comment: I don't think this will work. First of app because it would not be cross platform (iOS specific path) and second of all because the full generated path includes a reference to the app itself. Try removing your app from the device or emulator, and running it again. The picture will fail.