# how to send email in iphone/ android using intel xdk?

Tags: email, cordova, intel-xdk

I have imported [EmailComposer](https://github.com/jcjee/email-composer) Cordova plugin in my project. Now i am trying to call

```
window.plugin.EmailComposer.open({
                to:      ['max.mustermann@appplant.de'],
                cc:      ['erika.mustermann@appplant.de'],
                bcc:     ['john.doe@appplant.com', 'jane.doe@appplant.com'],
                subject: 'Hello World!',
                body:    '<h3>TEST</h3><h2>TEST</h2><h1>TEST</h1>',
                isHtml:  true
            });
```

method to send email with attachments. But i am getting following error

```
Cannot read property 'EmailComposer' of undefined
```

I don't know why this error coming. Even i dont know that EmailComposer plugin is imported or not in my project. Is there any way so i can confirm that.

Please provide your comments. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: hi, you cant use pluigns only when you build the app and launch it in you device, if you try to use them inside the emulator,app preview etc it will not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To confirm that plugin is installed, build your app in **[IntelXDK](http://xdk.intel.com)** and the build log should have a message that "EmailComposer plugin was installed".

Also Cordova plugins cannot be tested in IntelXDK emulator, you haev to build app and install on device to test an app that uses plugins